# Jupyter kernel is dead

Tags: kernel, jupyter

I have been trying since three-four days but my jupyter kernel is dead whatever you try. I am attaching screenshots of error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsODa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zUyv.png)

Please help me in this as I am really worked up in trying to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

REgards,
Sandhya

Comment: No, *screenshot* is a wrong way for demonstrate the code and the error message. Instead, they should be copy pasted into the question post as **text**. Please, read [ask] and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I found out how to revive kernel...thanks for ur help anyways